# Conditions when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions get called by the IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

Can anybody tell me in what all scenarios does the delegate function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called by the IOS apart from when app is launched for the first time. I launched the app into the device with XCode and removed the connectivity and then tried sending messages to the device through wifi. I then noticed that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions got called few number of times. Why is this happening and what are the conditions when this function gets called. I am not able to figure out all the scenarios.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a):

> You should use this method (and the corresponding application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method) to complete your app’s initialization and make any final tweaks. **This method is called after state restoration has occurred but before your app’s window and other UI have been presented**. At some point after this method returns, the system calls another of your app delegate’s methods to move the app to the active (foreground) state or the background state.

Answer (score 3):

Your question, can anybody tell me in what all scenarios does the delegate function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called by the IOS ?

If app is killed or in terminated state and user receives a local notification or remote push notification, and user taps notification, then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called first in both cases.

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions also gets called when you are monitoring location changes using "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges". From Apple

> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods of your app delegate contains the key location to indicate that your app was launched because of a location event.

Answer (score 1):

This scenarios described in [Launch Options Keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/launch_options_keys)

Comment: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey does this mean that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called every time there is a remote notification to be processed or anything else?

Comment: As I understand yes (when remote notification to be processed).

Comment: But it does'nt get called every time i receive a notification in my app.

Comment: Yes, it will be called only if your application not loaded before.

Comment: Does it mean "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" will be called only the first time users downloaded and run the app??

Comment: It means that it will be called only if your application not loaded `in memory` before

Comment: @CAMOBAP no it will be called: 1) When the user opens the app for the 1st time 2) When the user force closes the app and it opens it again 3) When the OS closes the app and the user opens it again . It will not be called when the app is brought back from background into forground.