# Installation of an iOS application from test flight shows location permission alert

Tags: ios, ios7, testflight

I am facing this weird issue when I install an iOS application from test flight on iOS7 device.

I see the location service permission alert (With 'Don't allow' and 'OK' buttons) momentarily on the screen as soon as the application installation is complete. The alert dismisses itself within a fraction of second.

Any pointers/solution to similar problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After continuous analysis of the code and reading other questions and blogs, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599487/conditions-when-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-get-called-by-the-ios) helped.

The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the code I am trying to debug has a singleton instance of a class which was invoking startUpdatingLocation of the CLLocationManager class.

I am assuming this will solve the issue once for all.

Comment: This indeed helped to fix the issue.

Comment: I developed with react native and a few native apis. Where in my code do I have to change things, and what?