# how to fix react-native app with location alert in testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, location, testflight

testflight is giving brief location alert and then going to background.

people asked about resolving with regular ios development. for example here: [Installation of an iOS application from test flight shows location permission alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864247/installation-of-an-ios-application-from-test-flight-shows-location-permission-al)

But I am developing with react-native and using an external location api package. Where in RN do I do any changes so that I can run the app in testflight?

Comment: do you have any code written in appDidFinishLaunching function in appDelegate.m file?

Comment: @SatishMavani this is the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pashute/Noam/feature/iosBeacons/ios/noam/AppDelegate.m